# Как ускорить выборку элементов List

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
private List<Document> FindDisabledDocuments()
{
    List<Document> disabledDocuments = new();
    if (User is null)
    {
        return disabledDocuments;
    }
    foreach (var d in Documents)
    {
        if (d.Users.Find(u => u.Id == User.Id) is null) // Users is List<User>
        {
            disabledDocuments.Add(d);
        }
    }
    return disabledDocuments;
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Several internal properties...
    public virtual List<Document> EnabledDocuments { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Several internal properties...
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Всё работает, но при большом количестве записей выборка занимает значительное время.

Как можно ускорить процесс выборки?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136461/discussion-on-question-by-curiousmax-----list).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `LINQ` запрос написать. Что-то такое, если я правильно понял логику метода:

```cs
private IEnumerable<Document> FindDisabledDocuments()
{
    if (User is null)
    {
        return new List<Document>();
    }
    return Documents.Where(d => !d.Users.Any(u => u.Id == User.Id));
}
```

`LINQ` запросы оптимизируются, возможно это будет быстрее работать.

Comment: Проверил. Также. Но Ваш код мне больше нравится :)

Comment: Извиняюсь за флуд. Так ещё короче: private IEnumerable<Document> FindDisabledDocuments() => User is not null ? Documents.Where(d => !d.Users.Any(u => u.Id == User.Id)) : new List<Document>();

Comment: LINQ в текущей реализации не может быть быстрее простых циклов. Именно поэтому он забанен при разработке компилятора Roslyn.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov О как. Отстал я от жизни видать. Это в `NET.Core` так или вообще?

Comment: @CuriousMax Да, можно через тернарный `if`, конечно, но мне кажется он несколько затрудняет чтение кода, поэтому я его не стал писать :)

Comment: В .NET Framework LINQ был тормозилкой. В .NET Core в каждой версии вводят новые оптимизации и постепенно LINQ ускоряется, что не может не радовать (эх, были бы макросы как в Nemerle - linq бы залетал). Есть библиотеки linq-rewrite, linq-optimizer, которые автоматически переписывают код в циклы.